# Extending Hash and (de)serializing from/to yaml

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

I found this example:
http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#extending_kernel::hash

It's nice to see how easy YAML can serialize a hash.
However, I would like to serialize my own class, an extended hash WITH the attribute in it.

What would the yaml-string look like and what would be the best way to serialize it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mladen Jablanović's answer shows, you can override `to_yaml`. You could add an array named 'attributes' (taking special care to escape that name if there is a key in the hash with that name (taking care to escape the escaped name if ... etc.)). However, you need some knowledge of the internals to make this work (the `out.map(tag_uri, to_yaml_style)` and its variations are nontrivial and not well documented: the sources of the various Ruby interpreters are your best bet).

Unfortunately, you also need to override the deserialization process. How you can reuse existing code there is close to completely undocumented. As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318253/custom-to-yaml-and-domain-type), you see you would need to add a `to_yaml_type` and add the deserialization code using `YAML::add_domain_type`. From there, you are pretty much on your own: you need to write half a YAML parser to parse the yamled string and convert it into your object.

It's possible to figure it out, but the easier solution, that I implemented last time I wanted this, was to just make the Hash an attribute of my object, instead of extending Hash. And later I realized I wasn't actually implementing a subclass of Hash anyway. That something is storing key-value pairs doesn't necessarily mean it *is* a Hash. If you implement `:[]`, `:[]=` and `each`, you usually get a long way towards being able to treat an object as if it is a Hash.

Comment: Ouch, I was already afraid I was going to need my own parser.
I hoped there was some easy and clean solution I couldnt find in the documentation :)

Maybe I indeed need to reconsider whether I want to extend Hash.
Not sure what's going to be the cleanest solution in my case, need to sleep on it :)

Thanks, at least I know now what I'm up against

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those things about Ruby that I really dislike: there are libraries in the core libs that have not been designed with some of the obvious use cases in mind and that are badly underdocumented to add insult to injury. This implementation of yaml should never have been allowed into the core libs.

Comment: It turns out I'm wrong about having to parse the string: the yamled string is partially unyamled and offered to you as a Hash. See for instance [here](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/custom-yaml-emitter.html), at the bottom. However, it still doesn't seem to allow you to defer part of the unyamling to the default unyaml of another class.

Comment: Instead of inheriting Hash, you should consider wrapping it in your class, and define its `to_yaml` simply as `{:custom_atts => {your_custom_attrs_here}, :hash => @wrapped_hash}.to_yaml` or so. BTW, I don't think current YAML implementation is badly written, rather underdocumented.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/syck/lib/syck/rubytypes.rb) of original `Hash#to_yaml` and override it, adding whatever you need:

```
def to_yaml( opts = {} )
  YAML::quick_emit( self, opts ) do |out|
    out.map( taguri, to_yaml_style ) do |map|
      # here you can add something like:
      map.add('my_attribute', @my_attribute)
      # and proceed with the usual Hash serialization:
      each do |k, v|
        map.add( k, v )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This will cause a problem if one of the attributes has the same name as one of the keys. Also, in deserializing, it will add your attributes to the Hash keys: the deserialized object will not have the attributes.

Comment: True. I just wanted to illustrate the principle. The format itself should be thought out first.

Comment: Confusion described the exact problem I bumped into. Is there a cleaner way?